# Static library and internationalization

Tags: xcode, internationalization, static-libraries

I have a question regarding static libraries. I need to localize some text inside my library. So I created a bundle where I put my different localized files. Then, I created a function like this :

```
NSString *MyLocalizedString(NSString* key, NSString* comment)
{
    static NSBundle* bundle = nil;
    if (!bundle)
    {
        NSString* path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyStaticLib.bundle"];
        bundle = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] retain];
    }

    return [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
}
```

But when I use it, it always return the english localized string (besides my phone langage is French). I do not know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got the very same issue when doing the exactly same: I've a static library and a companion bundle file with image, localized string, etc..

I've figured out that seems that the static can't figure out the correct device localization (I'm sorry but I wasn't able to find the reason of this issue) and I've fixed by doing this:

```
@implementation NSBundle (KiosKitAdditions)

+ (NSBundle *)kioskitBundle
{
    static NSBundle* kioskitBundle = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{

        NSString *libraryBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:KKBundleName
                                                                      ofType:@"bundle"];

        NSBundle *libraryBundle = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:libraryBundlePath] retain];
        NSString *langID        = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path          = [libraryBundle pathForResource:langID ofType:@"lproj"];
        kioskitBundle           = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] retain];
    });
    return kioskitBundle;
}

@end
```

As you can see I have created a category of NSBundle with a Class method that act very similar to `[NSBundle mainBundle]` and that return me the correct bundle for the static libray so I can use it everywhere I want, for example:

```
#define KKLocalizedString(key) NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(key, @"Localizable", [NSBundle kioskitBundle], @"")
```

The code is very simple first I find the path for the static library bundle, find the current device language and then I create a new NSBundle whose path is library_path/device_language.lproj .

A drawback of this approach is that you need to alway localize all of your asset and this can be a pain if you have a lot image in your bundle (but I think this is unlikely).

If you don't want to adopt my category approach you can change your code like this:

```
NSString *MyLocalizedString(NSString* key, NSString* comment)
{
    static NSBundle* bundle = nil;
    if (!bundle)
    {
        NSString *libraryBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyStaticLib"
                                                                      ofType:@"bundle"];

        NSBundle *libraryBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:libraryBundlePath];
        NSString *langID        = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path          = [libraryBundle pathForResource:langID ofType:@"lproj"];
        bundle                  = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] retain];

    }

    return [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
}
```

Comment: You're welcome Niko, please let me know if you can find what causes the problem.

Comment: Indeed, but no problem, I only have few images.

Comment: @Niko Does anyone understand why it doesn't work in normal way?

Comment: Hi Anastasia, not really. I did not try to investigate more on that question as it is working like this :)

Comment: How are you working with your localizable strings in a bundle? Xcode doesn't seem to let me drag localizable strings into a .bundle folder...

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the Storyboard tries to load its images from the localized bundle as well (which is practically a sub-folder within the main resource bundle), so it fails. In order for this to work one need to manually copy the images used by the Storyboard to each and every localized *.lproj subfolder within in. Which of course increase the bundle size dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

I had to modify Luca's answer to get it working how I wanted. My problem was very similar: Using my bundled localized strings from the consuming application didn't resolve to correct [lang].lproj folder. In my case, I had an es.lproj folder I wanted to look up from. However, if the user sets their preferred langauge to es-MX, using [NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] will try to find the es-MS.lproj folder, which doesn't exist.

```
@implementation NSBundle (CCPAdditions)

+ (NSBundle *)CCPBundle
{
    static NSBundle* corePaymentBundle = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{

        NSString *libraryBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ClipCorePayments"
                                                                      ofType:@"bundle"];

        NSBundle *libraryBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:libraryBundlePath];

        for (NSString *langID in [NSLocale preferredLanguages])
        {
            NSString *path = [libraryBundle pathForResource:langID ofType:@"lproj"];
            if (path)
            {
                corePaymentBundle           = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    return corePaymentBundle;
}

@end
```

This iterates through the preferred language list, and checks to see if that path exists. If es-MX.lproj is missing, it will next check es.lproj, etc. and eventually finds en.lproj if nothing else is there.